# How do I read the "ascii-art bar of metadata in file boundaries"?

Tags: radare2

Radare2 has an option, `p-`,

```
Usage: p-[hj] [nblocks]   bar|json|histogram blocks
| p-   show ascii-art bar of metadata in file boundaries
| p-h  show histogram analysis of metadata per block
| p-j  show json format
```

Using it though, I get a

```
[0x08048340]> p-
0x8048000 [..______ssss_ss__s_ssssfss^fsffssffsffsfszz] 0x8048538
```

without a legend. What do these different symbols mean `f`, `s`, `z`, `_`, `.`, and `^`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could get that by looking at the source code [here](https://github.com/radare/radare2/blob/a0844ef2c3a2e2852e975634686f0eca4a447093/libr/core/cmd_print.c#L2559-L2588).

Each caracter represent a different things that a block can contain. They are checked in order (so that it doesn't mean only one thing can be in any section) and each symbol marks the block that...

- `^` - you are in
- `z` - has strings
- `s` - has symbols
- `F` - has functions starting in
- `c` - has comments
- `.` - has flags
- `f` - has functions partially in
- `_` - has something else

But I agree a legend would be helpful. Maybe this should be documented in [r2 book](https://radare.gitbooks.io/radare2book/content/) or `p-?` should actually print the legend.